# Use of kinda and kind of in fiction

Tags: word-usage, formality, colloquialisms

I realize that "kinda" is an informal form of "kind of". However, would "kinda" be appropriate in fiction or dialogue? Or would it be more acceptable to stick to "kind of"? This is for a fiction novel from first person view.

Additionally, I found that when I write, I tend to use "kinda" for more informal sentences ("it was **kinda** freaky") and "kind of" for more serious sentences, I would use "kind of" ("I **kind of** knew how they felt"). Is this acceptable or would it be preferable to use "kinda" or "kind of" consistently?

Comment: This is arguably a better fit for http://writers.stackexchange.com

Comment: When you say _acceptable_, you should ask yourself "to whom?" In reporting speech or informal txting, _kinda, gotta, wanna, shoulda, shouldna, useta, oughta,_ and the like are perfectly fine, because they report what you say, which is the purpose of writing. In formal contexts, however, the hedging phrase _kind of_ itself is often viewed as vague; this is true, but vagueness is often viewed as ignorance or laziness. This is hardly a grammatical problem, but rather a social one.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based. Beyond that, ANYTHING is appropriate in fiction, as decided by the author. Of course, some readers might find ANYTHING to be inappropriate.

Comment: You have to ask yourself who is speaking.  If it's a supposedly literate narrator then "kinda", et al, should be avoided.  But if you are either quoting or writing in the voice of someone with a dialect then by all means make use of that dialect.

Comment: (For more on this topic, read *Huckleberry Finn*.)

Answer (score 4):

There are few hard and fast rules for dialogue, since you're trying to capture people's speech.  At one time, it was quite common to use a variety of creative misspellings to indicate different dialects.  In more recent times, readers tend to find this annoying and potentially offensive.

In this particular case, I think it would be perfectly fine to use "kinda," "kind of" or both as they suit your needs for either dialogue or a first-person narrative (I wouldn't typically use either for writing in the third person).  Just remember, even a few of these phonetic renderings tend to go a long way for most modern readers.